# Send data to a modal and back to the component in Angular/Bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, webpack, angular6

I have a list with users and I want to edit details of an user, using a modal. How can I pass data from the component's user list to the modal and then get those details back in the component code (so that an API is called)?

Here is the component code:

```
export class DeviceUsersInternalComponent implements OnInit {   
    @Input() summary: any;
    users: UserDetails[];

    updateCredentials() {
    }
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" *ngIf="summary">
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="thead">USERS</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
            <p *ngIf="!users">No Users</p>
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-borderless table-responsive" *ngIf="users">
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let us of users">
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-md btn-primary" 
                               data-toggle="modal" 
                               data-target="#changeCredentialsModal">{{ us.operatorId }}</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="changeCredentialsModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                <div class="thead">Change details for {{ us.name }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #changeCredentialsForm="ngForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <table class="table table-condensed table-borderless">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                                    <label>Name: </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="updateDetails()">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did tried with angular services? You can set data in to a service before open the modal popup and read the same on the modal once it's open.

Comment: @Code-EZ good idea, I'll try it.

Comment: and also if you want to work the change detection on component based on the new service data create a getter setter property on your component. get users():UserDetails[]{
    return this.service.UserDetails;
  }.something like this

Comment: you can use ng-bootstrap for the modal;, it has a ModalService which you can use to pass data from parent to Modal and open the modal dynamically from code . Then you can use an EventEmitter in your modal to return the data from service.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be sharing the data using Angular services.

set the data to be read from the modal component before it open

```
service.UserDetails=["Setting some data"];

modal.open() //code for open the popup
```

When you close the popup , if you want to make the angular change detection works based on the new service data, you can create a getter/setter property in component to sync with the new service data.

```
model.close()// when model close you can update the service property

service.UserDetails= ["Updated the data"];
```

In component you can do like below. So you don't need to call the change detection explicitly.Angular will automatically do it for you

```
export class DeviceUsersInternalComponent implements OnInit {   
    @Input() summary: any;
    get users():UserDetails[]{ return this.service.UserDetails; }

    updateCredentials() {
    }
}
```

or you can use [RxJS Subjects](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) or EventEmitter to send back data from the modal to the component and update the component property.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use angular-material, and their dialogs for this type of application.

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

It's really easy to use. You basically create a component for you modal, open it using a service, and it's easy to share data with it:
On the service side:

```
dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
   sharedDatas: 'test'
}
```

On the dialog component side:

```
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public sharedData: any)
```